# Shell script: find iconized programs , if found , activate it

Tags: bash, xorg, window

Stardict uses a tray icon , also allows multiple instance of itself ,  but sadly , i don't use a panel , so no notification area available.

But when I hit on close , it minimized to tray , is there a way to find its "Window" ? if the WId was found , activate this window by sending some X message ? I'm not sure if it's possible. (for hidden windows)

Thanks , and please provide a simple bash script

Comment: That's a good question - I have no idea where applications that minimize to tray go to if there is no tray running.  There are independent applications that provide a system tray without a full panel.  I started running stalonetray recently out of a similar need.

Comment: It's Window Manager dependent — by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [wmctrl](http://sweb.cz/tripie/utils/wmctrl/):

```
wmctrl -a Stardict
```

With [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/):

```
xdotool windowactivate $(xdotool search --class Stardict)
```

I used `Stardict` for the window class, check that this is right with `xprop` (run `xprop` in a terminal then click on a non-iconified Stardict window and check the `WM_CLASS` line).